# Generating a consecutive number from the database

Tags: c#, sql, algorithm

I'm currently working on a sales system for my project at school. After the sales operation is complete the item table has to be updated along with the sales table. The user doesn't input the sales invoice no. to the system, so the sales invoice no should be generated from within the system. can someone please help me on how to generate the sales invoice no.(consecutive no. from the previous invoice no.)
Regards

Comment: The thing you are looking for is [Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property) column.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a new table for the Invoices with an Identity column for InvoiceId and having a foreign key to InvoiceId in the sales table and update it whenever an invoice is generated?

Comment: So I made one table's primary key to auto increment and made it the foreign key of the other. Once data in input to the first table, I need to data into the second table, how can I insert this auto increment value to the second table.

Comment: Use the SCOPE_IDENTITY
Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql